# Regex to match all before specific string if exists (GA Data Studio)

Tags: regex

I'm a bit stumped and have tried some solutions from similar posts, but Google's Data Studio does not seem to like lookbehinds.

So far I have come up with the below to match text before "/products":

```
.+?(?=\/products)
```

However I also need it to return the complete test if "/products" does not exist.

- Eg 1:

  /sometext/somemoretext/products

should return: **/sometext/somemoretext**

- Eg 2:

  /sometext/somemoretext

should return: **/sometext/somemoretext**

Comment: Try `^(.+?)(?:/products|$)`

Comment: This is great thanks! I realized that I need to extract both before "/products" and "?utm" as some cases appear without.

Comment: I posted the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499001/3832970) with this addition and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
^(.+?)(?:/products|[?]utm|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h7oAzv/1). Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.+?)` - Capturing group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:/products|[?]utm|$)` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `/products|` - `/products` or
  - `[?]utm` - `?utm`
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.